# Как исключить index.php?

Tags: .htaccess

Есть index.php, на который перенаправляется все запросы. При этом все параметры сохраняются нормально. Но когда отправлен POST запрос на index.php теряются все данные. Насколько я понимаю, мне достаточно исключить корень и index.php из редиректа, чтобы всё работало как надо.

Помогите настроить перенаправление. Сейчас это криво выглядит вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Попробуйте ограничить правило типом GET, как-то так: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  =GET`. Условие с `REQUEST_URI` соответственно не надо.

Comment: @de_frag Спасибо за подсказку, всё заработало, но наоборот добавил строчку `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST`
теперь при post запросе на главную, все пост параметры не теряются, а при редиректе с других страниц, тоже по прежнему всё ок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итоговый .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Зачем пытаться исключить index.php, если он уже исключён, как существующий файл? `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: @vp_arth это от того, что конфигурации апача редко приходилось трогать :)  А так, действительно, строчка лишняя, спасибо что подметили.